# PostgreSQL 9.3: Dump a database excluding the data of some tables

Tags: postgresql-9.3, pg-dump

Consider a production database with a few dozens of normal-size tables, and a handful of huge tables.

I am looking for a convenient way to [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html) the database content, excluding the few huge tables, for my own local laptop. I can easily dump a small sample of the huge tables using `\COPY`, if I occasionally need to address these tables.

If I use the `--exclude-table=table` argument, both the schema and the data of the huge table is omitted, which breaks queries expecting these table on the local development environment.

**Is there a way to dump a data base with a complete schema, excluding the *content* of some given tables?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you need to use `--exclude-table-data=table` option. From the docs:

> `--exclude-table-data=table`
>
> Do not dump data for any tables matching the table pattern. The pattern is interpreted according to the same rules as for `-t`. `--exclude-table-data` can be given more than once to exclude tables matching any of several patterns. This option is useful **when you need the definition of a particular table** even though **you do not need the data** in it.
>
> To exclude data for all tables in the database, see `--schema-only`.

Comment: the table provided to --exclude-table-data (and --exclude-table) is a pattern (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS). If you want to exclude everything prefixed with something like `ks_` you write it as `ks_*` where * matches a sequence of any characters